# groupby Sum on columns of multiple dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes (df1 and df2) below. Based on the values of df1.col1 and df2.col1 , I want the values in df1.col2 and df2.col2 to be added. This sum total should then go against each row in df1 as a 3rd column. For example: wherever we have A01 in col1, the values in col2 should be summed. So 1+7+5=13. Same for all other col1 values.

To give further clarity, I have given a snapshot of how df1 should look at the end (End Result)

```
**df1
|col1  |  col2**   |   
|------| --------  |
| A01  |    1      |
| A02  |    0      |
| A03  |    0      |
| A01  |    7      |
| A02  |    1      |

**df2
|col1  |  col2   |    col3**
|------| --------|----------
| A01  |    5    |      x
| A02  |    0    |      y
| A06  |    0    |      asa
| A07  |    1    |      asa
| A02  |    4    |      st

END Result:
**df1**
**col1 |   col2  |    col3**
|------| --------|----------
 A01   |   1     |    13
 A02   |   0     |    5
 A03   |   0     |    0
 A01   |   7     |    13
 A02   |   1     |    5
```

Answer (score 0):

found a solution based on manipulating merge and groupby operations. 
First I grouped by `'col1'` df1 and `'df2'`, then calculated the sum, and finally merged with df1 the `'sum'`

```
dic_df1={'col1':['A01', 'A02', 'A03', 'A01', 'A02'], 'col2':[1, 0, 0, 7, 1]}
df1=pd.DataFrame(dic_df1)

dic_df2={'col1':['A01', 'A02', 'A06', 'A07', 'A02'], 'col2':[5, 0, 0, 1, 4] ,'col3**':['x', 'y', 'asa', 'asa', 'st']}
df2=pd.DataFrame(dic_df2)

print(df1), print(df2)
```

[image]

then perform a groupby on 'col1' so we can calculate the first part of the sum, and then when merging df1 and df2, we will have total sum in both datasets in column `'sum'`

```
df2=df2.groupby(['col1'], as_index=False)['col2'].sum()
merged=(df1.groupby(['col1'], as_index=False)['col2'].sum()).merge(df2, left_on='col1', right_on='col1', how='left')
merged['sum']=merged['col2_x']+merged['col2_y']
```

[image]

finally a merge on df1 with merged

```
df1=df1.merge(merged[['col1', 'sum']], left_on='col1', right_on='col1', how='left')
```

final output if df1:
[image]

There are many ways to fill the Nan value in final output df1.